# How to include https links with // on VS Code custom snippets JSON file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

While trying to create custom snippets on VS Code I am not able to create snippets that include `https://` because the JSON file apply comments after `//`.

Is there a way to avoid this?

[image: example]

Comment: Looks like it's just a syntax highlighting issue. If you ignore that, does it work anyway?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `/`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used a delimiter in the snippet that is the same as the json string delimiter: `"`

You could use single quotes for the href attribute in this example or just escape the string delimiter where applicable in the body value:

```
"Nunito Font": {
    "description": "Includes Nunito Font link",
    "prefix": [
        "nun",
        "nuni",
        "nu"
    ],
    "body": [
        "<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>"
    ]
}
```

[image]